# Python Image Directories

Tags: python, windows-7, python-imaging-library

Using PIL in python one must put the full directory for an image, so that the program runs properly. Is there any way to make that directory variable? So that it gets the programs current directory then looks for the images in that same folder?

This is in Windows 7 BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for: os.getcwd